# How to get first instance to last instance of a number in a string in javascript regex/ object error?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `"{\"id\":\"35112914\"}"` obtained after `JSON.stringify` .
I want just the number `35112914` or the first instance of a number ,i.e. `3` to the last ,i.e., `4` . Is there any other way of approaching this ?

Edit:
I had to stringify because of a weird error I was getting. While accessing the property of the object, i was getting `undefined` as the answer , which made the number inaccessible. Stringify atleast shows up the number .

Edit 2 :

My code is written in node which makes curl request to a REST api .

```
curl.request(optionsRun, function (error, response) {
                console.log(response);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    ID = response ;
                    console.log(ID["id"]) ;
                },2000) ;
            }) ;
```

Output:

```
{"id":"35113281"}
undefined
```

Comment: or parse the string: `JSON.parse('{\"id\":\"35112914\"}').id`

Comment: I would suggest sorting out the error

Comment: Might be worth posting the code that was giving the "weird error". If it's stringify-able, it's got to be readable on its own. That's how stringification *happens*.

Comment: no proper solution for that error was available .

Comment: Don't perform regexes on JSON objects...

Comment: "no proper solution for that error was available" - if that were true, `stringify` would have failed. There's a mistake, or a bad assumption, somewhere along the way. You can find ways to sort-of work around it, or you can correct it.

Comment: Are you modifying the response ? It looks like you're trying to build a bad workaround for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: What happens if you say `console.log(typeof response))` in addition to `console.log(response)`?

Comment: Nope, Why would I ? lol . setTimeout is for safety purposes because of a separate function .

Comment: @CrayonViolent response is taken in the closure...

Comment: You're also not parsing the response so obviously `console.log(ID["id"])` will return `undefined`.

Comment: I'd work on accomplishing whatever is clashing with another function in a promise.

Comment: @PaulRoub `typeof` shows string !!!

Comment: So, console.log(JSON.parse(response).id)

Comment: That's what I suspected. @Andy is right - you don't have an object. `response` is a JSON string. If you say `ID = JSON.parse(response);`, all should be well.

Comment: @PaulRoub Thanks ! nailed it ! Add as an answer please .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse your response to a JS object before you can access it using JS object methods:

```
curl.request(optionsRun, function (error, response) {
  var ID = JSON.parse(response);
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(ID.id) ;
  }, 2000);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c5gjf0un/4/)

Comment: Thanks for making `ID` local. That was troubling.

Comment: Yeah, had it in the demo, just forgot to carry it across to here :)

Comment: OP may have declared ID outside of the curl request? Which would still be worrying...

Comment: Then OP is free to re-globalize it. But starting out safely makes for a better example.

Comment: I need to keep it global . I am using it in other methods .

Answer (score 0):

this regexp will give you any numbers combination between two quotes
`/\"(\d+)\"/`

Comment: The OP has an error in his code that sound like it's easily fixable so you might find this answer is a little premature.